# xrandr will not detect monitor on DisplayPort

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xrandr, monitors, resolution

I recently got a new [ViewSonic](http://ViewSonic%20XG2703-GS) Monitor and was configuring it to 144 Hz using XRandr. It seems I messed something up and now, I can't get my monitor to work using DisplayPort. Only HDMI works.

This issue started after I typed `xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 144.00` into terminal and moved the mouse. The screen said "no signal". I turned the monitor and computer on and off and nothing happened. Switching to HDMI fixes the problem but then I can't use the 144 Hz. I think this is a Linux related issue and not a monitor related issue since the problem started after I edited the xrandr code. The only thing I can think of is changing the xrandr setting again but I can't do that since xrandr says that DP-0 is disconnected.

I have tried:

- Changing XRandr setting
- switching out DP cables
- Clearing monitor settings file

Edit: I just noticed that when I turn my computer on with DP-0 plugged in, my monitor briefly reacts before going into standby mode. Turning it on still says "No signal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly caused the issue but I solved the problem by [reinstalling the nvidia driver](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux).

Comment: You can also accept your own answers. Self-answered posts are popular things.